# How much water should be left in LG Front Loading Washer

Tags: washing-machine

I have a LG frontloading washing machine that is about 8 years old.  I have replaced the water discharge pump two times now.  The motor was always ok, but the plastic "vane" would break and free spin on the motor shaft.

How much water should I be able to drain out of the hose on the bottom left after it is fully pumped out?  Benchmarks I have done are typically between 4-5 cups (about a quart).  The water is "cloudy" and doesn't smell clean.  Is it reasonable to expect this much residual water?  My wife says it is causing the clothes to smell bad if left in the washing machine for more than 30 minutes.  She also thought in the past it never required draining this much water (i.e. when cleaning the filter).

Other notes:

- I am pretty sure there is no blockage.
- I have run the test mode, and all seems good.  The "frequency" does go up when the water drains.
- Could it be the water level sensor?  And this might be preventing it from fully draining?
- The discharge standpipe is about 4 feet above floor level.  Someone thought it could be a bad check valve, letting water contained in the hose flow back into the tub when the pump stops.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is no check valve, so water that doesn't make it over the curve at the end of the hose *does* flow back into the tub when the pump stops. This adds somewhat to the volume of water remaining in the machine.

Comment: That water should be almost drinking clean

Comment: @Ruskes keep in mind these front-loaders use a lot less water. But you're right, it should be cleaner. Probably not getting a full pump-out after the first cycle.

Comment: I think it might be that we are not doing regular cleanings.  I am going to do some tonight and see if that improves the water clarity.  This makes sense.  If there is a lot of "gunk" on the tub, that is probably holding water which eventually leaches down but after the final drain.

Comment: @Ruskes - after about 4 or 5 clean cycles (Clorox, vinegar, even pouch of store bought tub cleaner), the water is still cloudy/murky.  Could it be the case there is so much crud build up on the bottom of the drum it will take much more to clean?  Would it be difficult to take off the "basket" so I can physically clean it?

Comment: I just watched a YouTube video and the author says Citric Acid and Oxy Tablets works well.  He says it helps the longer these chemicals have to work.  Could I manually fill the tub with hot water (door open and off), add these chemicals and periodically agitate the inner basket?

Answer (score 1):

`I am pretty sure there is no blockage.`

`The water is "cloudy" and doesn't smell clean`

The pump goes through more than one pumping cycle.

First pumping after the washing cycle (dirty water), then pumping after the rinsing cycle.

You might have a problem with the drain air vent. It might be clogged or not present. The air vent is responsible for allowing water in the drain to flow freely and not be held back by the vacuum effect.

If you do not see or not know if you have air vent you can do a test. Insert a long rod or screwdriver securing it so it does not fall in, so to squish the drain hose to the side and create a air vent.

To your original question `How much water should be left in LG Front Loading Washer` I do not know, never measured it, but it should not be higher then the drum.

Answer (score 0):

My LG has a hatch, Front lower left.  My machine is about 8 yrs old as well.

Behind the hatch is a filter and a small drain hose.  My wife cleans it out once a month.  If left too long there is a musty smell in the drum.

There are instructions on the inside of the hatch.[image: Hatchenter image description here]    [image: 0pen hatch]

Comment: I am aware of this.  This is what I drain 4-5 cups of "cloudy" water out of each cycle.

Comment: Then that is normal.